# Convert a two dimensional byte array into a single dimenionsal byte array

Tags: c#

How to convert a jagged array of bytes into a single dimension. Example `byte[][] s1_byte` . Convert it into `byte[]`.

Comment: byte[][] is a jagged array and byte[ , ] is two dimentional.

Comment: how do i convert a jagged array to an single byte array

Answer (score 1):

try it with [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
int[][] i = new[] {new[]{1,1},new[]{2,2}}; // [1,1],[2,2]
int[] result = i.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray(); // [1,1,2,2]
```